# Computing the condition number of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, condition-number, octave

Given$$A=\begin{bmatrix}23.89&-36.48&1.432&21.65\\-36.48&54.58&-5.193&-34.45\\1.432&-5.193&-1.0717&1.937\\21.65&-34.45&1.937&20.50\end{bmatrix}.$$
I am given the eigenvalues of $A$ as $100$, $1$, $-0.1$, $-3$, which matches with an error of $10^{-3}$ the eigenvalues given by `octave`

```
A = [23.89 -36.48  1.432   21.65; 
    -36.48  54.58 -5.193  -34.45;
     1.432 -5.193 -1.0717  1.937;
     21.65 -34.45  1.937   20.50] ;

>> lambdas=eig(A)
lambdas =

   -3.001013
   -0.098193
    1.001209
   99.996297
```

With the definition of the conditional number $\kappa$:
$$\kappa_{2}(A) = \frac{|\lambda_{n}|}{|\lambda_{1}|},$$
I can compute the conditional number with:

```
kappa = abs(max(lambdas)) / abs(min(lambdas))
```

which gives the answer $33.333$.

However when I check the answer with the following `octave` command it does not match:

```
cond(A)
```

which gives $1018.4$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $\lambda_1$ in the formula is the eigenvalue of smallest modulus, not smallest value (and similarly for $\lambda_n$).

Comment: Conditional number is based on $\min \vert \lambda_i \vert$ which is 0.1. Not on $\vert \min \lambda_i \vert$.

Comment: Thank you @ParclyTaxel and mathcounterexamples. So I should write `kappa = max(abs(lambdas)) / min(abs(lambdas))` instead of `kappa = abs(max(lambdas)) / abs(min(lambdas))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is wrong. Corrected below

---

The condition number (in $L_2$ norm ) is the ratio of the maximum/minimum [singular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices).

This equals the ratio of  the maximum/minimum (absolute values of) eigenvalues only if the matrix is symmetric (or more general, normal)  <s>which is not the case here.</s>

```
>> svd(A)
ans =

   99.996297
    3.001013
    1.001209
    0.098193

>> 99.996/0.098
ans =  1020.4
```

---

This matrix is normal , hence, effectively, the ratio of maximum/minimum absolute value of eigenvalues gives the number condition. But you must first take the absolute value, then select the extremes.

```
> kappa = max(abs(lambdas)) / min(abs(lambdas))
kappa =  1018.4
```

This was rightly pointed out by  Parcly Taxel's comment.